# Blank PDF generated from Microsoft Access Report

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, pdf, report

I am using an access report (written by someone else) that has 3 sub reports. All will export to PDF,  except the following sub report which renders in access on screen, then gives me a blank PDF when I export.

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Format([Chg_TtlElecChg],"Currency")) AS Expr2 
SELECT (Format([Date],"mmm"" '""yy")) AS Expr1 
FROM xtblRate_Calc 
WHERE (((xtblRate_Calc.Name)="GSD" OR (xtblRate_Calc.Name)="GSDT") 
  AND (((Year([Date])*12+Month([Date])-1))<>"")) 
GROUP BY (Year([Date])*12+Month([Date])-1), (Format([Date],"mmm"" '""yy"))
ORDER BY Year([Date]), Month([date]) 
PIVOT xtblRate_Calc.Name;
```

I have tried to do a print preview from Access and get the following error:

> Your query does not include the specified expression 'Year([Date])'
>   as part of an aggregate function.

These are the results of the report datasheet I get when I double click the report -

> Exp 1    GSD    GSDT
>      May '15  4165   44651
>      Jun '15  5562   55272
>      Jul '15  4188   54257

I understand the concept that you can't use the SUM function and then not use the same elements in the GROUP BY but the syntax of this is way above my knowledge base.  I've tried various combinations to no avail.

Comment: Confused, you said it renders on screen but then say print preview triggers error. Is this the SQL of a query object? The query opens? Did this report ever work properly? Edit question to show sample data. Try removing the ORDER BY Clause.

Comment: This is the SQL that is in the Row Source of the report in the Design View.  Correct, the results on screen are fine, if I export to PDF, the body of the report is blank, If i print to a PDF, the body of the report is blank, if I print preview from Access, I get the aggregate function error.  I don't know if it worked before, although I suspect it did.  Removing the Order by Clause produced another error in the print preview

Comment: Removing the Order by Clause produced another error in the print preview and I get an error when I try to Export but if I click ok, the report renders in the export!! Not ideal but at least it works:)  THANK YOU!